# Magento catalog rules discount issue

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I used the To Percentage of Original Price option to achieve the positive discount, with a Discount Amt of 110 (percent). First off, if I use the To Percentage of Original Price option to specify a typical discount (< 100%, so let’s say 90% for this example), Product Search for my test item shows a base customer price of $11.11 and discounted price of $10.00. This was correct.

But When I modify the associated Rule to specify a positive discount using a Discount Amount of 110% of Original Price, the Product Search shows this:

E.g. product price is 11.11 Promotion is "To Percentage of Original Price" is 110% It was increasing from 11.11 to 12.22 Front end shows price of 12.22 and as low as 11.11

How I can fix this issue